# Why HttpServletResponse is always created by ServletContainer and we cannot create it

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

Servlet API defines doGet as :

```
public void doGet ( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
```

Why it has not been defined as ( which looks more intuitive to me ):

```
public HttpServletResponse doGet ( HttpServletRequest req )
```

I do understand that ServletContainer creates an instance of HttpServletResponse  and passes to our doGet() method; but why we are not given a way to create this object and return it ?

Comment: Because that's they way they designed it. What practical difference would it make?

Comment: I have the impression that you're mixing the responsibilities of a web/HTTP front controller (Servlet) and a MVC action controller (JSF backing bean action, Struts action class, Spring MVC action, etc). If you indeed mixed up them, then this strange question would make somewhat more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you want to do it? In other words - how would an instance of `HttpServletResponse` created by you, would achieve more than the one coming from the container?

Anyway, here are a few reasons:

- some methods have strict contracts (e.g. you can't add more headers after all headers are sent). How would a container ensure whether this is properly implemented?
- some of the methods require significant amount of low level details, e.g. `encodeUrl`. Why give this burden to the user?
- methods like `sendRedirect`, `sendError` and others require immediate container action. If you would create `HttpServletResponse` yourself, there's fair amount of chance this action would be unnecessarily delayed until you exit `doGet`.